# show horizontal scroll in mat-select-panel

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I can't get to show horizontal scroll in `mat-select-panel`. I get to show it in every option with :

```css
::ng-deep.mat-option-text.mat-option-text {
    overflow: auto;
    text-overflow: unset;
}
```

But I want the scroll to appear at the bottom of the mat-select-panel. I'm trying this

```css
::ng-deep.mat-select-panel.mat-select-panel {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

In fact mat-select-panel shwos overflow: auto when inspecting the element. But it only shows the y-axis scroll.

I have made a stackbklit.

https://angular-mat-select-example-xton8x.stackblitz.io